# Can Nico Robin really reveal the void century?

Tags: one-piece

Nico Robin's goal is to find out what happened in void century that written in poneglyph, and she must read all the poneglyph to know the history.
Poneglyph is said scattered around the world, and each poneglyph is connected to another poneglyph.

But can she really read all the poneglyph and reveal the void century?

Because if I'm not mistaken about the Log Pose, it will point to the nearest island. How about there's some island missed by Mugiwara Crew and possibly have a poneglyph, that's mean Nico Robin can't read the poneglyph and she also can't reveal about the void century.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes, she can.**

What you said about her requiring to visit all poneglyphs to decipher the Rio Poneglyph is true and has been stated in the [Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Poneglyph) also:

> Only when the stones are read as one will they fill in the Void Century of the world.

However, it also says:

> **There are two types of poneglyphs: those that carry information about how to reach the other poneglyphs and those that carry the records of the "True History".**

**Hence, even if she were to miss an island, she would be guided there by another poneglyph.** Finding the island is not much of a problem either because one can use an [Eternal Pose](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Eternal_Pose):

> Like a Log Pose, it records the special magnetic waves of a certain island within the Grand Line, allowing the user to know which way to go to arrive at their destination. **Unlike a Log Pose, which resets its recordings on new islands, an Eternal Pose always points to the same island, no matter how long it stays elsewhere.**
>
> **They appear to be available for purchase, though come at a high cost.**

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is said that the true history is revealed by the Rio Ponelyph alone. According to One Piece's wikia page:

> According to Robin, the Rio Poneglyph (...) is the message carried by all the poneglyphs along the Grand Line. It contains the true history of the One Piece world (including the "Void Century" of which research is forbidden). In order to find it, one must take all other passages from the other Poneglyphs with them on their travels, and it is only completed upon reaching the end of the world; in other words, the island Raftel.

Therefore, we can argue that all the Poneglyphs are required to reach Raftel in the first place. However, this is probably not true since none of the Poneglyphs so far even talked about Raftel. Things may change as the crew gets closer and closer to the end of Grandline.

Also it is important to note that in her search of the void history, Robin is not starting from scratch. In her flashback during the Enies Lobby arc, professor Clover shares his hypothesis about the void history to the Gorosei ("Five elder stars" in Japanese) while Robin is listening. He and the other archaeologists from Ohara had already uncovered much and seemed close to the truth according to the Gorosei's reaction upon hearing it.

Comment: What you quoted doesn't imply that there's a Rio Poneglyph on the Raftel Island. Rio Poneglyph translates to "True Text of History". It **is** necessary for Robin to have seen all the poneglyphs in order to figure out what happened in the Void Century/the whole history (unless she fills in the gaps on her own by predicting what a missing poneglyph or two might have stated, which is **very** unlikely.

Comment: Yes, even in One Piece, it has not been shown or proven that the Rio Poneglyph is on Rafter. I think it only says (I'll have to find the reference) that it is "believed" it is on the last Island of Grandline. Also, the quote says that the Rio Poneglyph "contains the true history of the One Piece world". It would not matter if she missed some Poneglyphs on the way, since the Rio Poneglyph is said to contain it all.

Comment: That's the thing. Doesn't it contradict this:  "In order to find it, **one must take all other passages** from the other Poneglyphs with them on their travels"

Comment: well, I agree with @AshisGupta, "and **It is only completed upon reaching the end of the world**; in other words, the island Raftel." She need to know all the poneglyph